# How do I properly render a private file URI with l()?

Tags: 7, files

If given a private file with a uri of `private://Screenshot from 2015-12-07 15-52-42_0.png`. How might I use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) to properly render the link?

[image]

When rendered as follows I see `https://server/drupal-private-file-system/Screenshot%20from%202015-12-07%2015-52-42_0.png` instead of `system/...`. in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) is what I was after. I'm able to find what I was after with that.

`dpm(file_create_url($file_obj['uri']));`